# How to execute a Python program without any interruption when we change the shell or switch the Linux users inside the program?

Tags: python, linux, shell

Scenario: I made one program where I am taking the input file and execute the shell commands inside the file line by line using Python. But I noticed when we change the shell or switch the user, the execution stops on the go.

**Input File:**

```
# cat commands.txt
free -m
touch hi
ls -lrt
su - user
```

**Code:**

```
# cat mylinux.py
# This program is to interact with Linux

try:
        import os
        import subprocess
        import shlex

        print("This is an interactive linux session using Python! \nHere if you want to exit the session, type exit as the input command")
        print("Your RHEL OS version is "+subprocess.run(shlex.split("cat /etc/redhat-release"),stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode())
        i = input("Enter the file name: ")
        inputfile = open(i,"r")
        for line in inputfile:
                o=subprocess.run(shlex.split(line), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode()
                print(o)
except FileNotFoundError:
        if i != "exit":
                print("Please re-run the script and make sure to give some valid commands.")
        print("Thank you for using your PyShell!")
except IndexError:
        print("Bye! Next time, type some valid commands")
```

How would I make sure this works even when the shell or user changes?

Comment: Every command except the last one is being finished, but not the last one. `subprocess.run()` wait's until command returns an exit code, but `su - user` doesn't return anything until exited

Comment: So how would I execute any further commands in the same program?